# Problema con ajax en Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Tengo un select y una tabla cargada en Ajax. El problema me sale cuando dentro de esa tabla le doy al botón eliminar y me sale un mensaje como que me paso del límite: La primera vez funciona, la segunda cuando son varias variables no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a pasar un array y cuando son varias variables me salta ese mensaje. Porque al usar el select si que me carga la tabla que está en la misma función.

He cambiado en php.ini por si fuera eso las variables a:
post_max_size=64M
upload_max_filesize=64M
output_buffering=4096
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit=256M

Y me sigue saltando el mensaje.

El código Ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


var existe=false; 

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#cambiarplanta").change(cambiarPlanta);

        $idplanta = $("#cambiarplanta").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sacarPorAjax',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#cambiarplanta').html(response).fadeIn();
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert('web not found');
                }
            },
            error: function (x, xs, xt) {
                window.open(JSON.stringify(x));
                //alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(x) +"\n error string: "+ xs + "\n error throwed: " + xt);
            }
        });




    }); //fin funcion ready 


    function cambiarPlanta() {

        if (existe == true) {
            $nombrecompuesto = $("#nomcom").val();
            $idcompuesto = $("#idcom").val();
            $idplanta = $("#idplan").val();

            var array1 = [$nombrecompuesto,$idcompuesto,$idplanta]

            alert("hola "+array1);

            var resultado = {
                'array': array1
            };
            var url= 'prueba';

        } else {
            $idplanta = $("#cambiarplanta").val();
            var resultado = {
                'array': $idplanta
            };
            var url= 'cambiarDePlanta';
        }
        existe=false;           

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: resultado,
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {

                $('#sacarCompuestos').html(response).fadeIn();



            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert('web not found');
                }
            },
            error: function (x, xs, xt) {
                window.open(JSON.stringify(x));
                alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(x) + "\n error string: " + xs + "\n error throwed: " + xt);
            }
        });
    }


    function eliminarCom() {
        existe = true;

        cambiarPlanta();
    }
```

Lo que muestra Antes de darle al botón Eliminar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando vayas a enviar datos mediante el método de HTTP POST, intenta usar un formData en vez de un array.

```
let frmData = new FormData(); 
frmData.append('nombre_variable', variable); 

$.ajax({ ... })
```